# xpath element can't be found only when using unittest class

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The weirdest thing ever:
I'm running a program from a module which is calling some functions from another module.
The thing is that the same code will run perfectly while using basic functions but the third function will fail only when using it inside the unittest class, with the below message:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
>   element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="app_skeleton"]/tbody/tr[6]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[9]/a"}.

The below is the full class:

```
  from Main_Package.General_Functions.Functions import 
  login,search_by_customer_id,add_subscriber_iden_and_activate,browser

class FirstTest(unittest.TestCase):
  @staticmethod
  def test_login():
     login()

 @staticmethod
 def test_search_by_customer_id():
     search_by_customer_id()

@staticmethod
def test_add_subscriber_iden_and_activate():
    add_subscriber_iden_and_activate()




#login()   ******this is the block of code that will run perfectly without # 
****
#search_by_customer_id()
#add_subscriber_iden_and_activate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Well it's pretty self explanatory, at the exact moment your program tries to locate the `WebElement` using the given selector, it cannot find it via the provided selector. Please for the love of all that is holy, stop using *XPath-selectors* for starters as it will **NEVER** be faster than *CSS-selectors* (the server first has to convert the `DOM` into `XHTML`). Also that selector is incredibly **BRITTLE**. Shorten it, use a 2 element combo for maximum effect where the first is your *anchor* / *container* and the second is your *targeted element*. You might also need to explicitly wait for it.

Comment: Nope, already tried to use CSS instead and it's the same. The solution is not around this area. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute unit tests you have to be sure that the specific test has the "environment" prepared in order to execute the test.

The execution of the tests isn't in order, so the:

```
test_add_subscriber_iden_and_activate()
```

could be executed before of the

```
test_login()
```

You can use the methods `setUp()` and `tearDown()` if you want to execute something before and after **each** tests or `setUpClass()` and `tearDownClass()` if you want to execute something before and after **all** the tests.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) the documentation.